# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.equals(org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive)'

Tags: spring-boot, bouncycastle

Getting below error in my springboot application .
I searched the issue it looks like I have conflicting libraries .

below class is present in 2 different library and IntelliJ is confused which one is the source .

```
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

When I clicked on Unknown source it is showing two source

```
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.68 , bcpkix-fips-1.0.5
```

Anyone has some idea which one is latest library to keep ?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.equals(org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive)'
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.createPemObject(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

Maven version

```
----------------------Maven Version--------------------
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Users/psingh6/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.11.0-11/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-fips</artifactId>
            <version>${bouncycastlepkixfips.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bc-fips</artifactId>
            <version>${bouncycastlefips.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you have a compatible version on your application's classpath and that you don't have both bcprov-jdk15to18 and bcprov-jdk15on.

Comment: The issue is because of multiple(bouncycastle) jars with different versions.Removed the old entry and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , there was conflict between below libraries

```
org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.createPemObject : bcpkix-jdk15on-1.68 , bcpkix-fips-1.0.5

org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter.writeObject : bcprov-jdk15on-1.56 , bc-fips-1.0.2.1
```

Now, I am keeping only below lib in my pom.xml and it works !!!

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Note: By clicking on Unknown Source in IntelliJ idea gives clear idea where is the conflict .**